# We're unable to connect to store at this moment on 8.1 error after resetting the phone

Tags: store

I had to reset my mobile,but after the reset when i try to access the store it keeps showing up the above mentioned error in title.what are the necessary steps to close this problem.

Comment: Is the date and time accurate on your phone?

Comment: yes I did,I tried all the necessary steps,but couldnt.Finally had to reset my device again and chose an older backup,with that backup I was able to connect to the store.Is there no other way to fix this?